# substr with quotation mark doesn't work properly on php?

Tags: php

Why My [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_substr.asp) doesn't work properly? Here is my code:

```
<?php
echo substr("list:[\"76801-2\"", 7,12);//output 76801-2"
?>
```

the output is: `76801-2"` while I want it to be: `76801`

I looked on [w3 schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_substr2)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: `7, 12` means *take 12 characters starting from index 7*. It does not mean *index 7 through 12*. http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `substr` is the length of the new string you want to extract from your current string.

This means that in your case - you take 12 chars starting from the 7th char.
The total length of chars (from position 7) is 7, which is less than 12, so the result will be the entire string.

If you want to take only 5 chars, you can use:

```
echo substr("list:[\"76801-2\"", 7, 5);//output 76801
```